# JQuery UI Draggable how to get drag start position

Tags: jquery

I can drag my draggable items and drop them on my droppables and get the drop position from
ui.absolutePosition on the drop event. I need to know what position the drag started from.
I have tried getting ui.position on the drag start event but this is null. I've also tried
ui.position on the drag event but this is undefined.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use the ui.draggable from the .droppable's drop function to get what you're after.

```
ui.draggable.offset()
```

perhaps.

If you want the exact mouse position on start of drag, you can use the event.clientX and event.clientY on the .draggable() start function

```
$('selector').draggable({ ...options...
      start: function(event, ui) {
                   alert("You clicked x:" + event.clientX + " y:" + event.clientY);
             }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Saving the client.x, client.y gives what I need.

Answer (score 3):

A possible better way might be to save element's start position in data

```
jQuery("selector").draggable({
    start: function(event, ui) {
        // Log start dragged position to element data
        jQuery(this).data('startPosition', jQuery(this).position());
    }
});
```

So you can use it later or also in other functions ..... e.g.

```
stop: function(event, ui){
     Startpos = jQuery(this).data("startPosition");
     alert("DragStart : Left("
          + parseInt(Startpos.left) 
          + ")Top(" + parseInt(Startpos.top) +")"
     );
}
```